# Making pascal's triangle show in the cmd for c++

Tags: c++, algorithm

So I got this code to work, because luckily I remembered function prototypes! I'm pretty new to C++. I'm really curious how I would make this turn into an actual triangle using spaces somewhere. I admit I haven't worked tireless to try to figure this question out. I'm just looking for it to **not look like the the picture**, **but an actual triangle.** Much help would be appreciated.

[image]

```
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

void genPyrN(int rows) 
{
  if (rows < 0) return;
  // save the last row here
  std::vector<int> last(1, 1);
  std::cout << last[0] << std::endl;

  for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
    // work on the next row
    std::vector<int> thisRow;
    thisRow.reserve(i+1);
    thisRow.push_back(last.front()); // beginning of row
    std::transform(last.begin(), last.end()-1, last.begin()+1, std::back_inserter(thisRow), std::plus<int>()); // middle of row
    thisRow.push_back(last.back()); // end of row

    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
      std::cout << thisRow[j] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    last.swap(thisRow);
  }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    using namespace std;

    genPyrN(9);
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to using `iomanip`'s `setw`, you can add a number of spaces based on the row at the start of each row to get an isosceles triangle structure

```
for (int k = i; k < rows; ++k)
{
  std::cout << "  ";
}
```

For example, if you know your values will fit in three digits:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

void genPyrN(int rows) 
{
  if (rows < 0) return;
  // save the last row here
  std::vector<int> last(1, 1);
  for (int k = 0; k < rows; ++k)
  {
    std::cout << "  ";
  }
  std::cout << std::setw(3) << last[0] << std::endl;

  for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
    // work on the next row
    std::vector<int> thisRow;
    thisRow.reserve(i+1);
    thisRow.push_back(last.front()); // beginning of row
    std::transform(last.begin(), last.end()-1, last.begin()+1, std::back_inserter(thisRow), std::plus<int>()); // middle of row
    thisRow.push_back(last.back()); // end of row

    for (int k = i; k < rows; ++k)
    {
      std::cout << "  ";
    }
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    {
      std::cout << std::setw(3) << thisRow[j] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    last.swap(thisRow);
  }
}
```